# unable to Validate Custom components in SmartGWT

Tags: smartgwt

I am unable to get my custom compoenent to be validated in the dynamic form. I tried many versions but it is not working as expected. For e.g. either the label is not showing in BOLD to indicate the field is mandatory and it aloows to save the form without entering anything in the field. Only when the user enters something in the field and deletes it, then the red icon is displayed to the user that the field is mandatory.I dont know what i am missing. please help. code is below

[image]

```
telnumber = new CustomTelephoneTextItem();
telnumber.setName("tel");
telnumber.setTitle("Tel");
telnumber.setTitle(nerpweb.clientFactory.getMessages().tel());
```

Below is my Custom  TextItem which i am using in the above class

```
public class CustomTelephoneTextItem extends CanvasItem
{
    textField_value = new CustomIntegerItem();
    textField_value.setShowTitle(false);
    textField_value.setWidth(100);
    textField_value.setRequired(true);

    form.setItems(textField_value, textField_code);
    form.validate();

    setWrapTitle(false);
    this.setCanvas(form);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to item title showin bold, you must call item's setRequired(true).

in your code is telnumber.setRequired(true);

Second, if you want to validate item on form.validate(), you must override validate() function in your item and write validation code in this function.

in your code is call form.validate() in CustomTelephoneTextItem validate() function

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to be implemented to validate custom component

This code will go in your Custom component which you will implement

```
@Override
public Object getValue()
{
    if (validate() && textField_value.getValue() != null)
        return textField_value.getValue();
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setRequired(Boolean required) {     
    super.setRequired(true);
}

@Override
public Boolean validate() {     
    return super.validate();
}


@Override
public void setValidators(Validator... validators) {
    textField_value.setValidators(validators);
}
```

Then in the class where you will create the custom component you will call the setRequired() method,like so

```
telnumber.setRequired(true);
```